# Seeking a solution to update multiple Excel workbooks in the same directory?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to automate updates to multiple Excel files.

(I might be running into incorrect file path calls)

My code:

```
Sub UpdateFiles()
    MyDir = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
    DataDir = MyDir & "\folder1\"
    ChDir (DataDir)
    Nextfile = Dir("*.xlsx")
    While Nextfile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open (Nextfile)
        Workbooks(Nextfile).Sheets("sheet1").Range("F22") = "Major"
        Workbooks(Nextfile).Save
        Workbooks(Nextfile).Close
        Nextfile = Dir()
    Wend
End Sub
```

Would like data in cell F22, on sheet1, to read "Major"

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Here re some answers I did recently [Open and Import File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989467/how-to-open-multiple-workbooks-to-copy-the-data-from/53990323#53990323), [From Workbooks Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019876/how-to-gather-data-from-all-rows-from-differenet-excel-workbooks-and-sort-them/54026784#54026784) to see the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## * Instead of x

The pattern **`"*.xls*"`** enables the opening of both **.xlsx** and **.xlsm** files and additionally **.xls** files

### The Code

```
Sub UpdateFiles()
    MyDir = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
    DataDir = MyDir & "\folder1\"
```

> `Nextfile = Dir("*.xls*")`

```
    While Nextfile <> ""
        With Workbooks.Open (Nextfile)
            .Sheets("sheet1").Range("F22") = "Major"
            .Save
            .Close
        End With
        Nextfile = Dir()
    Wend
End Sub
```